# Comparing Points of graph to a line in chart vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, charts, mschart

I have a chart which contains a graph and line as reference. I want to test if there's 9 consecutive points are on the same side with respect to the reference in other words if they have greater or smaller value y of the line.So i tried to make a compare y-values of points with y-value of my reference line by using the function Findbyvalue but that didn't give me any result this is my code: 
Any ideas; thank you in advance

```
     Dim index As Integer = 0
    'Find first point with a Y1 value of 13.
    Dim dataPoint As DataPoint = Chart1.Series("Rend").Points.FindByValue(13, "Y1", index)
    While Not (dataPoint Is Nothing)
        dataPoint.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 128, 128)
        'Find all other data points with a second Y1 value 10.
        index += 1
        dataPoint = Chart1.Series("Rend").Points.FindByValue(13, "Y1", index)
          If index = 8 Then
            Exit While
          End If
    End While
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution which is too simple : copy the Yvalues of the graph to an array and then make any test you want on the array.

```
 Dim yArray(Chart1.Series("Rend").Points.Count) As Double
    Dim temp() As Double
    For i = 0 To Chart1.Series("Rend").Points.Count - 1
        temp = Chart1.Series("Rend").Points(i).YValues
        yArray(i) = temp(0)
    Next
```